# in java, using regex to find address = "..." in xml

Tags: java, regex

I'm using java regular expression to find

```
address = "..."
```

in an xml document, however, in Java, an expression like

```
String regex = "address = "...""
```

is not legal. Is there any way to get around this?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe backslash the inner quotes? Something like `String regex = "address = \"...\""`

Comment: why don't you use XML parsing API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes,

```
"address\\s*=\\s*\\\"[^\"]*\\\""
```

Example:

```
String s = "foo address = \"foobar\" ";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("address\\s*=\\s*\\\"[^\"]*\\\"");
//System.out.println(s.matches(pattern));
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(s);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
 String ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
 System.out.println(ResultString);
} //=> address = "foobar"
```

Comment: +0.5 for `[^\"]*` instead of `.*?` - and another .5 for optional whitespaces :-)